# Spring Retry not working and getting exception for maxAttemptsExpression value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere, websphere-portal, spring-retry

I am using `spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar` and using below `Retryable` annotation in service methods

```
@Retryable(value = {CustomException.class}, 
            maxAttemptsExpression = "#{'${max.retry.attempts}'}", 
            backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{'${retry.delay}'}"))
```

In the logs seeing below exception due to `maxAttemptsExpression` value and same error when we used `Interger.ParseInt/Interger.ValueOf` also.

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from
>   java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

I see this exception only on few  @Retryable service methods and remaining  @Retryable methods are working fine. I have no idea what's happening here and we see the value also before hitting to annotation

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#{'` and `'}` (including the single quotes).

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${max.retry.attempts}")
```

The `#{...}` is not needed here.

You should also upgrade to 1.2.1.RELEASE.

**EDIT**

Something else must be going on; both forms work fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So48309090Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48309090Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                foo.foo();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {

            }
            try {
                foo.bar();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {

            }
        };
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${max.attempts}")
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo");
            throw new RuntimeException("c");
        }

        @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{'${max.attempts}'}")
        public void bar() {
            System.out.println("bar");
            throw new RuntimeException("c");
        }

    }

}
```

application.properties

```
max.attempts=5
```

and

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
```

Comment: Same exception after changing to below  and updating to 1.2.1 RELEASE                       
@Retryable(value = {CustomException.class}, maxAttemptsExpression = "${max.retry.attempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.delay}"))

Comment: Something else must be going on; both forms work for me; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: spring-retry [is here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

Answer (score 0):

`EL1001E` is also the error that is raised when the property is not found. Try binding your property to an instance variable with `@Value` and checking that the value is actually being read from the properties correctly.